# Building Android application inside android OS

Tags: android, build, android-install-apk, aide-ide

Im curious to know the what steps/tools need to build an android app from source code to apk inside android (i.e. inside an android powered smartphone).

Im actually curious how [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en) works. They give a whole integrated development environment as an android app. Without any root privilege, it compiles==>builds==>generates apk==>deploys/installs apk to host machine (i.e the smartphone).

Im guessing I need [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/)/[Gradle](https://gradle.org/) , [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) , [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html)(to sign apk).

But:

- What tools?
- In what sequence?
- How? :)

I dont know is it a good place to ask? If not, any suggestion of stackexchange network or any blog will be appriciated.

Comment: "Im curious to know the what steps/tools need to build an android app from source code to apk inside android" -- they would be the same steps/tools needed to build an Android app from source code to an APK outside of Android. However, relevant interpreters or binaries would need to be ported to run on Android and, usually, ARM CPUs.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your response, can you give me some code samples?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra tools, if you have AIDE installed...
Just wrap up your Android project code, hit the 'Build' button & it Compiles everything to a working Android App (.apk) :)

Answer (score 0):

*All you need is just **AIDE** .*
*IT HAS ALL REQUIRED TOOLS LIKE GRADLE, AAPT, SIGNER ETC*
*Just chill and start using AIDE, if you have problem with free version, try Pro. Am using Pro without any problem since 3 years*